# Unable to reduce the space between the label and control

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reduce the space between `kendo-datepicker` and `label` EvalDate in my form. I tried things like padding etc but its not helping.

Screenshot:

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group row col-md-12" style="margin-top:30px">
  <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-1  col-form-label " style="font-weight: bold;">Eval Date</label>
  <div class="col-md-1">

    <kendo-datepicker style="width: 100% ;float: left;"  [format]="'MMMM yyyy'"  [topView]="'decade'" [bottomView]="'year'" [(ngModel)]="evalDate"
      (valueChange)="evalDateChanged($event)">
    </kendo-datepicker>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left: 10px; width: 100%"><a class="btn btn-primary "
      (click)="downloadFundAllocationDetails()" [attr.href]="Url">Export To
      EXCEL<i title="PDF" class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> </a></div>
</div>
```

Screenshot after applying Thanveer's solution
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a negative margin-right on the label?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you put the label inside the same div as the input and remove the `col-md-1` from label

```
<div class="form-group row col-md-12" style="margin-top:30px">
  <div class="col-md-1">
 <label for="inputFax" class="col-form-label " style="font-weight: bold;">Eval Date</label>
    <kendo-datepicker style="width: 100% ;float: left;"  [format]="'MMMM yyyy'"  [topView]="'decade'" [bottomView]="'year'" [(ngModel)]="evalDate"
      (valueChange)="evalDateChanged($event)">
    </kendo-datepicker>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-left: 10px; width: 100%"><a class="btn btn-primary "
      (click)="downloadFundAllocationDetails()" [attr.href]="Url">Export To
      EXCEL<i title="PDF" class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> </a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution. The datetimepicker and label are not in the same level. Slightly distorted

Comment: Oh Sorry, Can you post a screenshot of the current situation? Cuz the date picker is not visible for us , You might be using a plugin , maybe that's why it's not visible

Comment: Added screenshot to the post

Comment: The label , the datepicker and Button have to be on the same line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `bootstrap 4` you can wrap `label` and `date-picker` in same `column`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="inputFax" class="col-form-label " style="font-weight: bold;">Eval Date</label>
     <kendo-datepicker style="width: 100% ;float: left;"  [format]="'MMMM yyyy'"  [topView]="'decade'" [bottomView]="'year'" [(ngModel)]="evalDate"
  (valueChange)="evalDateChanged($event)">
</kendo-datepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <a class="btn btn-primary " (click)="downloadFundAllocationDetails()" [attr.href]="Url">
      Export To EXCEL <i title="PDF" class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> 
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the css properties like `margin`, `padding` in the class `col-form-label`. Since, you're using it for `<label>` tag that might be adding some space.

If there are no stylings in the `col-form-label`, try to put the whole `<label>` inside a new `<div>` element. Hope it helps!